# How to get selected option with raw javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <select name="select">
     <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" onclick="processForm(this.form)">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function processForm(form) {
  console.log(form)
}
```

I can successfully get the form as HTMLElement but cannot seem to find easy way to get selected value

Comment: What do you want to do with the form?
Do you only want the values or you want to send it to a server as a POST method??

Comment: there is a selectIndex attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're sending the form object itself on submit, getting data is easy in vanilla JS. Modify your function to:

```
function processForm(form) {
  var selected = form.select
  console.log(selected.value)
}
```

Note that `select` is not some special property of the form, it's just because that's what you gave the name attribute for the select element.

Comment: I'd change your HTML to give the `<option>` different values too so you can differentiate between them.